# Avoid creation of duplicate sheet

Tags: vba, excel, duplicates

I am trying to make a macro to make budgets.  I have different business units with multiple cost Centers.  basically I want to circulate this macro enabled worksheet to different business units and they make budget with the predefined parameters.

While doing the setup, the user selects a business unit, then the available cost centers under the same business unit creates one sheet each with predefined names.  Now the problem is, if the user go to the same setup again and select the same business unit, it will show a run time error that the sheet name cannot be changed as one sheet with same name already exist.

I tried to use On Error function, but a new sheet is created with eg: Sheet16.

My requirement is either to continue with the file as if nothing happened or pop up a MsgBox with the predefined error message without creating a new blank sheet.

Any ideas?

Comment: It would be easier to help if you edit your question to include the code you've tried.

Answer (score 2):

You can first check if the sheet exists and handle that situation. You can use the following loop:

```
For Each i In ActiveWorkbook.Sheets
    s = i.Name    ' this is the name
Next i
```